# React multiple api calls in one action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

just starting with redux and have an issue that I find myself hard to handle.

I have an API call (with Axios) to fetch some data

```
onFormSubmit(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 this.props.fetchTracks(this.state.term);
}
```

Action file -

```
export function fetchTracks(term){

  var params = {
   api_key: API_KEY,
  };

   const request = axios.get(URL, { params: params });

   return {
    type: FETCH_TRACKS,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

Reducer -

```
export default function (state = [] , action) {
  switch(action.type) {
   case FETCH_TRACKS:
    return [action.payload.data, ...state];
  }

 return state;
}
```

For now, all works great and I get the data as expected.
From this point, I want to get some data from this API call that I just did and have another API call to another url with this data.

How should I do it? Have another API call in the current action? have another action?

Basically, How should I handle two API calls with the same action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As axios uses promises, you can chain them

```
return axios.get(...)
.then((response) => {
     return axios.get(...); // using response.data
})
.then((response) => {
      return {
          type: FETCH_TRACKS,
          payload: response.data;
      };
});
```

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/708

Comment: Using your way I am getting the payload/request as undefined

Comment: This is returning the promise to `request`, not the data returned from the request. You need to do your payload return inside the last `.then` were you have access to `response.data`.

Comment: Updated my answer to better reflect your scenario.